# Why document.onreadystatechange runs twice?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have the following example below. I am curious why the console log writes the line 'document is ready' twice (both in FF as well as Chrome). How can I make sure it only runs once?

Additional question: since I am also using `window.onload` that already has an event attached, is it possible to add a window event without removing previously assigned ones?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload=function(){console.log('window is ready');}
            document.onreadystatechange = function(){console.log('document is ready');}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/api/document/readystate it explains all 3 states of document.readystate. Yes you can add additional event to the window, without removing previously assigned event/s.

Comment: It's fired everytime the ReadyState _changes_, inside the function you should check what the ReadyState is yourself and act upon that.

Comment: Thank you! the link explained is very well! :)

Comment: it sounds like you probably want to bind the `DOMReady` event...

Answer (score 5):

It runs multiple times because it have multiple states

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

`loading, interactive, complete`

If you want to catch only one of them, just filter it using code similar to the one you see by the link